# Find disk attached to vm using govc

Tags: go, virtual-machine, vmware, vsphere

I was looking to find the details of the Virtual Machine using [govc](https://github.com/vmware/govmomi/tree/master/govc).

I was able to fetch the details of the instance using `govc vm.info`, but the result had details of CPU, Memory, IP Address and other not about **disk storage**, which I can see on vsphere console or by logging into system.

Is there any using `govc` to find the disk attached to the instance ??

Answer (score 3):

I asked this on [govc's Github repo](https://github.com/vmware/govmomi/issues/597).

You can use:

To get `<path/to/vm>`, use

```
govc vm.info vm-name-here
```

To get all the details of the VM

```
govc ls -l -json <path/to/vm>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also get information about devices using

```
$ govc device.info -vm VirtualMachineName
```